# Iter 2: Reusable, robust c++ std::hash<mpz_class> for GMP's big integer type

Tags: c++, hashcode, gmp

This is the 2nd iteration of a code review. The 1st iteration (completed) is at
[Iter 1: Reusable, robust c++ std::hash<mpz_class> for GMP's big integer type](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244307/iter-1-reusable-robust-c-stdhashmpz-class-for-gmps-big-integer-type)

**1. Goal**

My intention is to provide a fast hashing algorithm to hash [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)'s big integer type `mpz_class` and `mpz_t` so I can use these types as keys for an `unordered_map`. The code shall be reusable for others.

**2. Current Approach**

Since C++17, the standard library provides the specialization `hash<string_view>` which is used to produce the initial hash value.
First, the magnitude data of the big integer is wrapped into a `string_view` and then its hash value is calculated using `hash<string_view>`. This produces an initial hash value which only depends on the magnitude, but not on the sign, of the big integer.
To keep the hashes of positive and negative big integers different, the initial hash value is scrambled once for negative big integers only.

**3. Code**

File **`hash_mpz.h`**:

```
#ifndef HASH_MPZ_H_
#define HASH_MPZ_H_

#include <gmpxx.h>

namespace std {

template<> struct hash<mpz_srcptr> {
    size_t operator()(const mpz_srcptr x) const;
};

template<> struct hash<mpz_t> {
    size_t operator()(const mpz_t x) const;
};

template<> struct hash<mpz_class> {
    size_t operator()(const mpz_class &x) const;
};

}

#endif /* HASH_MPZ_H_ */
```

File **`hash_mpz.cpp`**:

```
#include "hash_mpz.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <string_view>

constexpr size_t pi_size_t() {
    if (sizeof(size_t) == 4) {
        return 0xc90fdaa2; // floor(pi/4 * 2^32)
    } else if (sizeof(size_t) == 8) {
        return 0xc90fdaa22168c234; // floor(pi/4 * 2^64)
    } else {
        throw std::logic_error(
                "sizeof(size_t) not supported. only 32 or 64 bits are supported. you can easily add the required code for other sizes.");
    }
}

inline size_t scramble(size_t v) {
    return v ^ (pi_size_t() + (v << 6) + (v >> 2));
}

namespace std {

size_t std::hash<mpz_srcptr>::operator()(const mpz_srcptr x) const {
    string_view view { reinterpret_cast<char*>(x->_mp_d), abs(x->_mp_size)
            * sizeof(mp_limb_t) };
    size_t result = hash<string_view> { }(view);

    // produce different hashes for negative x
    if (x->_mp_size < 0) {
        result = scramble(result);
    }

    return result;
}

size_t hash<mpz_t>::operator()(const mpz_t x) const {
    return hash<mpz_srcptr> { }(static_cast<mpz_srcptr>(x));
}

size_t hash<mpz_class>::operator()(const mpz_class &x) const {
    return hash<mpz_srcptr> { }(x.get_mpz_t());
}

}
```

File **`main.cpp`**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <unordered_map>

#include "hash_mpz.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    mpz_class a;

    mpz_ui_pow_ui(a.get_mpz_t(), 168, 16);

    cout << "a      : " << a << endl;
    cout << "hash( a): " << (hash<mpz_class> { }(a)) << endl;
    cout << "hash(-a): " << (hash<mpz_class> { }(-a)) << endl;

    unordered_map<mpz_class, int> map;
    map[a] = 2;
    cout << "map[a] : " << map[a] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**4. Question**

Is there anything which can benefit from further improvement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Make functions that should not be exported `static`

Functions that should only be available locally should be marked `static`. This applies to `pi_size_t()` and `scramble()` in `hash_mpz.cpp`.

## Avoid using `std::endl`

Use [`"\n"` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n), the latter is equivalent to `"\n"`, but also forces a flush of the output. This is rarely necessary, and might hurt performance, especially when writing to a file, or when standard output is redirected to a file.

## Consider not `using namespace std`

It's very good that you are not `using namespace std` in the header files. But consider [not using it at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), since even if only used in `.cpp` files it can result in namespace conflicts that are hard to debug. If you do find yourself typing `std::` a lot and want to avoid it, consider only importing the names that you do use from `std::`, like so:

```
using std::cout;
using std::unordered_map;
```

## Final nitpicks

- There's still one unnecessary `std::` inside the `namespace std` block in `hash_mpz.cpp`.
- You don't need `return 0` at the end of `main()`.

Comment: Regarding your sentence "Functions that should only be available locally should be marked static.", does "locally" mean "inside of the same file"?

Comment: Yes. Inside the same [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

### You're not my library!

I think it unwise to add additional symbols to `std`. It's great to use a namespace for the purpose of defining a library, but it's both surprising and confusing for a third-party user to need to use `std` to get your code which is not STL code. Just make your own name.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the code in this way? It's not as trivial as it looks.

Comment: cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072248/why-arent-template-specializations-allowed-to-be-in-different-namespaces